# Django query inclusive of Foreign Attributes

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this model class:

```
class question(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True,null=False)
    paper_id = models.ForeignKey(paper,null=True)
    question_no = models.SmallIntegerField('question_no',max_length=6,null=True)
    content = models.TextField('content',null=False)
    topic_id = models.ForeignKey(topic,null=True)
    subtopic_id = models.ForeignKey(subtopic,null=True)
    std_answer = models.CharField(max_length=128,null=True)
    marks = models.IntegerField('marks',max_length=2,null=True)
    input = models.CharField(max_length=512,null=True,default=None)
    type_answer = models.CharField(max_length=512,null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=512,null=True,default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

I need to list all its attributes, inclusive of Topic.Title, Subtopic.Title, and Paper.Title which resides in foreign objects Topic, Subtopic, Paper respectively. How may I do so in a single query?

Comment: Have you looked into [django-haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) or [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)?

Comment: sorry, i rephrase the question in case misunderstanding. i need to get the object's attribute with its foreign attribute's title. its somewhat like SELECT attr1, attr2,... fk1.title, fk2.title FROM Questions INNER JOIN all_the_related_tables

Comment: @jdtoh: What do you mean by 'list all its attributes'?

Comment: i need to select: id, paper_id.title, question_no, content, topic_id.title, subtopic_id.title, std_answer, marks, input, type_answer, type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your models.py must be like this for example:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    .....

class SubTopic(models.Model)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    .....

class question(models.Model):
   question_no = models.SmallIntegerField('question_no',max_length=6,null=True)
   content = models.TextField('content',null=False)
   subtopic = models.ForeignKey(Subtopic)
   .....
```

You don't have to put id because django will create it for you.

views.py

```
def page(request):
return render(request, 'page.html', {
    'topics' : topic.objects.filter()
}

if you want to get by id

def page(request, id):
    topics = topic.objects.get(pk=id)
return render(request, 'page.html', {
    'topics' : topic
}
```

Your model class is incorrect. You don't have to put many foreignkey. One foreignkey is OK.

```
{% for topic in topics %}
    {{topic.title}}

    {% for subtopic in topic.subtopics  %}
        {{subtopic.title}}

        {% for question in subtopic.questions %}
            ............
        {% endfor %} 
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: yes, technically is incorrect. however this was done by previous colleague long ago and might be quite a hassle to clear it off. currently sticking with this.

Comment: do you have a queryset form for that? this one is rather inefficient

Answer (score 0):

To filter based on Foreign Key attributes, use the FK Model name followed by a double underscore, then the attribute name:

```
query = question.objects.filter(topic_id__title="foobar")
```

To easily create complex queries use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Comment: sorry, i rephrase the question in case misunderstanding. i need to get the object's attribute with its foreign attribute's title. its somewhat like SELECT attr1, attr2,... fk1.title, fk2.title FROM Questions INNER JOIN all_the_related_tables